# Click on webpage using cursor coordinates

Tags: vba, excel

Can any one help me to click on a web page using cursor coordinates.
Tip: Button don't have ID & name

Comment: You could use [mouse_event](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/mouse_event.html) to click

Comment: Will you give me a demo code for it.

Comment: What's not working with the example @Ripster already provided?

Comment: which website, which button?

Comment: Yes, we can click on button even if it doesn't have ID or name.

Comment: Gaurav, as Portland Runner points out, Ripster's link has example code.  Try adapting it to your purposes and if you run into issues, edit your question to include the code you create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of moving the mouse and clicking using [mouse_event](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/mouse_event.html):

```
Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
                                              ByVal dx As Long, _
                                              ByVal dy As Long, _
                                              ByVal cButtons As Long, _
                                              ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = &H1          ' mouse move
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2      ' left button down
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4        ' left button up
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = &H8     ' right button down
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = &H10      ' right button up
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = &H20   ' middle button down
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = &H40     ' middle button up
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = &H800       ' wheel button rolled
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = &H8000   ' absolute move

Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type


Sub Click()
    Dim pt As POINTAPI
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long

    '(0,0) = top left
    '(65535,65535) = bottom right
    x = 65535 / 2
    y = 65535 / 2

    LeftClick x, y
End Sub

Sub LeftClick(x As Long, y As Long)
    'Move mouse
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE + MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, x, y, 0, 0

    'Press left click
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE + MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0

    'Release left click
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE + MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Sub
```